# Invalid field names in Azure Search

Tags: azure-search

I am getting the following when trying to build my index:

`The request is invalid. Details: definition : Invalid field name: 'end date'. Field names must begin with a letter and can contain only letters, digits, or underscore`

I don't want to rename my field in Sitecore to not have spaces, so I need to somehow create a mapping so Azure Search accepts the field name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is solved by specifying a `cloudFieldName` attribute to the `<field>` element:

```
          <field fieldName="end date" 
                 cloudFieldName="end_date"
                 storageType="YES" 
                 indexType="UN_TOKENIZED" 
                 vectorType="NO" 
                 boost="1f" 
                 type="System.DateTime" 
                 settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure" />
```